# Asp.net CORS is configured, but not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, cors, websecurity

I have a web `API` written in `asp.net core 5`.

`CORS` is configured like below:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            string[] allowedOrigins = _config.GetValue<string>("AllowedOrigins")?.Split(",") ?? new string[0];
            options.AddPolicy("Default", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            });
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyThing", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
                // .AllowCredentials();
            });
            options.AddPolicy("Controlled", builder =>
           {
               builder.WithOrigins(allowedOrigins);
           });
        });
```

and `appsettings.json` contains the below part:

```
"AllowedOrigins": "http://localhost:4200,https://localhost:4200",
```

the client is `Angular 11.2`

when I try to consume the api through the client application,
it fires up "CORS ERROR" even if I remove and disable `CORS` in `API`.

I think the problem is from client side, but I don't know how to fix it.
Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Do you have CORS enabled in the Configure method in Startup.cs using the correct policy name? It's the first I'd look at (since it's not covered in your post).

Comment: It is configured truely.
I found sth,and it maybe the solution,
As I use http for client,and http for server,
Also I have app.UseHttpsRedirection();
maybe this is the restriction.

Comment: I tried with no UseHttpsRedirection() but it happend again.
the error I catch from browser is :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/Controller/Action' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
test-errors.component.ts:42

Comment: I added localhost:4200 to allowed origins array and happily it worked.

Comment: If you solved your own question put the answer in the Answer box below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer. That will mark the question as solved in the UI. Do not put “Solved” in your title; that does not mark your question as solved.